# HTML jquery vs. doing it manually

Tags: jquery, html

i need to load images as the user selects.

i am hoping to load them using DIV, but how to do it?

jquery can do it and it is in javascript, i believe.

so how can i write a function that manages div completion or is it too complicated?

just looking for clarity at this stage.

thanks.

edit: well i have drop down listing and as user selects one option i need to load a bunch of images. i would like to cache the images and then show them.

i can show you my site but that would be advertising.

```
  <select id="videodromeMenu" onchange="doDestination('videodromeMenu');">
                <option>Choose Your Destination...</option>
                <option>Pawns In The Game</option>
                <option>Akira</option>
                <option>Apocalypse Now</option>
                <option>Blade Runner</option>
                <option>Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon</option>
                <option>Dr. Strangelove</option>
                <option>Enemy at the Gates</option>
                <option>Nikita</option>
                <option>Out Of Africa</option>
                <option>Pulp Fiction</option>
                <option>Scarface</option>
                <option>Silence Of The Lambs</option>>
                <option>The Abyss</option>
                <option>The Big Blue</option>
                <option>The Thirteenth Floor</option>
       </select>
```

here is some code but wont really help i think.

Comment: Load images from where as the user selects what using what method? What is "div completion"?

Comment: Show some code or my answer is `purple`

Comment: Clarify what you mean by loading images as the user selects.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?  "as the user selects".  Selects what?  Images?  Selects how?  By clicking a link?  Via a select element?

Comment: how the user will select the images?

Comment: please read my edits also please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<select id="imageList">
    <option value="purple.jpg">Purple.jpg</option>
    <option value="red.jpg">Red.jpg</option>
    <option value="blue.jpg">Blue.jpg</option>
</select>

<div id="imageDisplay"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '#imageList' ).change( function() {
        $( '#imageDisplay' ).empty() // remove what's currently in the div
        $( '#imageDisplay' ).html( '<img src="' + $( this ).val() + '" />' );
    });
</script>
```

This will obviously need tweaking... especially the paths to the images.  but it's basically what I -think- you're looking for.

Comment: this is great. it saves me learning and using something like jquery. many thanks.

Comment: um... I wasn't actually trying to dissuade you from learning :(

Comment: i know but learning a whole package that is jquery just for this (this is all i need) would be too much. i like to learn! :)

Comment: It's probably important to know what you're doing rather than copying and pasting your way into a nightmare

Comment: I had hoped that I'd posted enough that he could learn from it, but not so much that he could just copy/paste/implement and move on.